# Less variables: how do I choose just 1 of several sets of colours?

Tags: less

I want to define multiple sets of brand colours and select only one of them to use at build time (with Grunt).

For example (in pseudo-code):

```
@brand: null;

if @brand = brand1 {
  @colour1: red;
  @colour2: blue;
  @colour3: green;

  @globalTextColor: @colour1
  @bodyBackgroundColor: @colour2
  @linkTextColor: @colour3
  @linkTextHoverColor: @colour1

} 

if @brand = brand2 {
  @colour1: orange;
  @colour2: black;

  @globalTextColor: @colour1
  @bodyBackgroundColor: @colour2
  @linkTextColor: @colour1
  @linkTextHoverColor: @colour1
}

otherwise {
  @colour1: pink;
  @colour2: purple;
  @colour3: cyan;
  @colour4: white;

  @globalTextColor: @colour1
  @bodyBackgroundColor: @colour2
  @linkTextColor: @colour3
  @linkTextHoverColor: @colour4
}

body {
  background: @bodyBackgroundColor;
  color: @globalTextColor;
}
a {
  color: @linkTextColor;
}
a:hover {
  color: @linkTextHoverColor;
}
```

And then in Grunt set the @brand variable before running the less build.

I'm really struggling to find a way to do this with Less, (but seems fairly simple in Sass).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow and thank you for composing a nice question with sufficient code to understand what you wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [pattern matching](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-parametric-feature-pattern-matching), like so:

```
@brand: null;
.setColors(@brand); //call setter mixin

.setColors(null) { //default
  @colour1: pink;
  @colour2: purple;
  @colour3: cyan;
  @colour4: white;

  @globalTextColor: @colour1;
  @bodyBackgroundColor: @colour2;
  @linkTextColor: @colour3;
  @linkTextHoverColor: @colour4;
}

.setColors(brand1) { 
  @colour1: red;
  @colour2: blue;
  @colour3: green;

  @globalTextColor: @colour1;
  @bodyBackgroundColor: @colour2;
  @linkTextColor: @colour3;
  @linkTextHoverColor: @colour1;    
} 

.setColors(brand2) {
  @colour1: orange;
  @colour2: black;

  @globalTextColor: @colour1;
  @bodyBackgroundColor: @colour2;
  @linkTextColor: @colour1;
  @linkTextHoverColor: @colour1;
}
```

Also, in your original code you posted, you omitted the semicolons after some of the color settings, so you would need to have those to get it to parse okay.

### Explanation

When you set the `@brand` variable, that will be used in the `.setColors(@brand);` mixin call, which then will look for a "match" to the "pattern" of the variable setting, and if found, outputs those color variables for use. If not found, you would get a compilation error of `No matching definition was found for` with the pattern that did not match, which will tell you that you have not defined that "brand" setting.